# Can't call recorded macros in vim

Tags: vim, macros

I've recorded a macro in vim by pressing <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> in normal mode and then did a few movement commands and wrote text to the document using <kbd>a</kbd> to enter insert mode. I then pressed <kbd>ESC</kbd> to get back to normal mode and finished the macro recording with <kbd>q</kbd>.

Now I want to run the recorded macro by pressing <kbd>ALT GR</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> for the `@` sign (I'm using a german keyboard layout) and then <kbd>1</kbd> because I saved the macro to the 1-register. But after typing the `@` in normal mode, vim shows me `:wincmd w` in the status line and doesn't run the macro after pressing <kbd>1</kbd>.

Am I missing something? Or do vim macros work different on german keyboard layouts?

**Edit:**

```
:registers 1
--- Registers ---
"1   A<br ><80>kb/>^[
```

Comment: You can run the command `:registers 1` to see if the macro was recorded in that register. And perhaps map `@` to some other, more accesible, key or key combo (e.g. `<leader>q`)

Comment: yes, the macro was recorded to the register. I've added the output of `:registers 1` to my question. `:map <leader>q @` has the same result.

Comment: Try `:noremap <leader>q @` - it's possible you have a map already for `@`? (but before that, restart Vim without your remapping and do a `:verbose map @` to see if some plugin/your vimrc messed with the key)

Comment: `:verbose map @` outputs this: `@             :wincmd w<CR>`. Don't know where this comes from though. Maybe from one of the plugins I've installed. `:noremap <leader>q @` works. I'd accept it as answer if you'd post it ;)

Comment: It's not a good idea to use a numbered register for macros - "Numbered register 1 contains the text deleted by the most recent delete or change command" so it will be quickly overwritten.

Comment: BTW, `verbose map @` should also state, on its 2nd line, which is the script from where it was set, e.g. something like "Last set from ~/.vim/plugged/vim-peekaboo/plugin/peekaboo.vim"

Comment: @moopet - true, but `:h q` allows for it, and the OP shows that the macro *is* recorded in the `1` register. I agree that using a letter would be better.

Comment: Yeh, I've saved the macro to `q` now anyway because it's easier to type (my leader key is `,`): `,qq` :) Thanks for that hint though @moopet. And btw: Obviously I was the idiot who mapped `:wincmd w` to `@` - it was in my `.vimrc` ^^

Comment: Heh - you'd be surprised to find out how often this happens ... people *love* to cannibalize other people's `vimrc`s, before they truly understand if they need all that stuff ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The described behavior shows that `@` was mapped by a plugin/script that Vim loads (mapping available with `:verbose map @`). One solution would be to capture the original `@` functionality in another key combo:

```
:noremap <leader>q @
```

.. and use that instead of `@`. The other solution - to remove the original mapping, either directly (script, vimrc) or by using the configuration options of the "offending" plugin.